# action_search cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I am following developer.android to do their training. I am in the process of "Adding the Action Bar", however, i encountered a problem.

In the section "Respond to Action Buttons" here (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html#Respond), the line "case R.id.action_search:" has error which says "action_search cannot be resolved or is not a field".

[Delete] In fact, the line "openSearch();" and "openSettings();" have red lines as well, saying "The method openSettings() is undefined for the type MainActivity". [/Delete]
(I know what is wrong here, I need to declare those two methods by myself.)

what should I do? Thx for the help first.

Comment: just add menu file in dir: res/menu/main_activity_actions.xml. containing <item android:id="@+id/action_search"/>. as explained in developer site

Comment: yes i did, but it still has the error message. I now change that into <item android:title="@+id/action_search"/> , and the error message is gone. But why is that?

Comment: This declares that the Search action should appear as an action button when room is available in the action bar, but the Settings action should always appear in the overflow.explained in developer site

Comment: Thx for the answer, but what confuses me is that why "android:id="@+id/..." gets error while "android:title="@+id/..." doesn't? Or is my changes on the original code wrong? if so, what should I change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Firstly, the attribute `android:id="@+id/action_search` has no problem.

There are two things you need to do that the tutorial seems to have taken for granted

- Add an image called "ic_action_search.png" to all the res/drawable directories in your project.
- Add the definition for the string resource "action_search" which is being assigned to the `android:title` attribute. Open the res/values/strings.xml file and add 
  `<string name="action_search">Search</string>` over there.

Secondly,

The functions openSearch() and openSettings() need to be defined in the same class by you. Something like :

```
public void openSearch()
{
      //Do something here.
} 
public void openSettings()
{
      //Do something here.
}
```

their functionality is not important for the tutorial as they are trying to show how you can control what happens when an option on the action menu is selected.

Answer (score 1):

Go Project->Clean
It worked for me

Answer (score -1):

I tried it and had the same problem. I removed `android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"` (instead of adding the images because I'm lazy) and added the action_search string in the resource file to make sure the menu file wasn't referring to anything that didn't exist. After that, I tried changing `android:id` to `android:title` because I saw that it had worked for you, and this was curious. It caused an error after saving, and so I changed it back. After changing it back and saving, the original error in the MainActivity.java file disappeared, and `R.id.action_search` was resolved. I think the problem is just that R.java is not being updated, and you have to basically hit it with a hammer by forcing an error and fixing it, at least in my case. I don't know why using `android:title` worked for you. Hope this helps somehow.